# Structure: SQL table fields with sub options

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting back to working with mysql through phpmyadmin. I am trying to create a simple table that involves information for an educational institution. I am needing help in determining how to structure the table fields. Specifically the `type`, `create` and `status`. Two of those involve options.

```
create table academy
(
  id int not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(25) not null, 
  street_address varchar(50) not null,
  city char(25) not null,  
  state char(25) not null,  
  country char(25) not null,  

  primary key (id),
 );
```

Details of table in plain text
academy

- Name ID
- Auto Increment
- Street Address
- State/Country
- Telephone
- Email
- Type

  - Elementary
  - Middle School
  - High School
- Created - (date academy
  started)
- Status

  - Active
  - Inactive

Comment: Can you tell us how the data will be used? PS - download MySQL Desktop - it will change your life.

Comment: Not sure if I understood well. But The data will later be used in conjunction with other tables like `courses` etc.

Comment: You might use data in many different ways - mailing lists, accessing student information in an administrative database, allowing students to access the information. Who will be entering the data? I'll put a tentative "answer" below, but more info would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, accessing academy information in an administrative database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very preliminary suggestion (I do stuff similar to this).

Here is one suggested structure:

```
uniqueid - autoincrement (a "database" ID)
studentid - varchar(x) - (a "useable" ID by the students/administration)
lastname - varchar(x)
firstname - varchar(x)
middlename - varchar(x)
street1 - varchar(x)
street2 - varchar(x)
city - varchar(x)
state - varchar(x) - (decide if you want full name California or abbreviation CA)
postalcode - varchar(x) - all numbers for US, mixed for Europe
telephone1 - varchar(x) - home phone
telephone2 - varchar(x) - cell phone of student
email1 - varchar(x) - email of student
email2 - varchar(x) - email of parent
level - enum ('Elementary','Middle School','High School')
admitdate - date
status - enum ('Active','Inactive')
```

Putting that table together in MySQL Workbench will take about 10 minutes.
I'm sure others will have better ideas.